# Question On Function Growth rate

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computer-science

Assume we have the grow rate of $log(n^{2n})$, $log(n!)$, $n(log(n))^3$, $n(2^n)$, $n^{(1.5)}$,$n^{(log(log(n)))}$,$\sqrt{2^{log(n)}}$,$2^{(\sqrt{log(n)})}$,$2^{(log\sqrt{n})}$,$2^{(2n)}$, $(log(n))!$ and $n!$

we can categorize them into 
Log:  $log(n^{2n})$ <  $log(n!)$ 
Linear:$n(log(n))^3$ < $n(2^n)$
Polynomial: $n^{(1.5)}$< $n^{(log(log(n)))}$
Exponential:$\sqrt{2^{log(n)}}$ < $2^{(2n)}$ < $2^{(log\sqrt{n})}$ < $2^{(\sqrt{log(n)})}$
Factorial: $(log(n))!$ < $n!$
Since Constant < Log < Linear < Polynomial < Exponential < Factorial, therefore the final order will be: 
$log(n^{2n})$ <  $log(n!)$ < $n(log(n))^3$ < $n(2^n)$ <$n^{(1.5)}$< $n^{(log(log(n)))}$<$\sqrt{2^{log(n)}}$ < $2^{(2n)}$ < $2^{(log\sqrt{n})}$ < $(log(n))!$ < $n!$ 
Is this the right way to process it or did I made any mistake on the grouping or ordering process?

Comment: There are several mistakes. $n \cdot 2^n$ is in no way linear, $2^{2n}$ is definitely not slower than $2^{\log \sqrt{n}}$ or $2^{\sqrt{\log n}}$ (which are also in the wrong order), and $(\log n)!$ grows much more slowly than you think. When in doubt, take logs and for the factorials apply Stirling's approximation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks! I'll look into it!